# Is there a way to exclude lines of code from code coverage measurement using coveragerc?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pytest-cov

I am using pytest, with coveragerc to measure code coverage of my source file, which is given below

```
import argparse
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
     parser.add_argument('--input_dir', type=str, required=True, help='fully qualified directory path')

     arguments = parser.parse_known_args(sys.argv[1:])
     my_func(arguments.input_dir)
```

My coveragerc configuration is given below

```
[report]
exclude_lines =
    if __name__ == .__main__.:
```

pytest config

```
[pytest]
python_files=*_test.py
addopts = --cov='.' --cov-config=.coveragerc
```

Tests to validate functionality in `my_func` exist, but not for the lines of code under main function. I would like to be able to exclude all lines within the main function from the code coverage because its functionality just initialises the parser and calls the another function.

Comment: The set up was taken from documentation. https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.3.3/excluding.html

Comment: I would expect this to work.

Comment: Link is broken. As of today this looks as the good one: https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.5.0/excluding.html